# How can I get the MacBook Pro trackpad to work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, macbook-pro, windows-8, touchpad

I can't seem to get the trackpad to work on my MacBook Pro. I have tried the Boot Camp drivers with no luck.

Does anybody know what drivers are needed for Windows 8 and a MacBook Pro trackpad?

EDIT: With Windows being out for a while now, anybody got a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: I use an external mouse as a workaround. Have not yet been able to find a solution myself.

Answer (score 5):

From: [How do i get my macbookpro trackpad working with Windows 8? - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-hardware/how-do-i-get-my-macbookpro-trackpad-working-with/f702c409-b05c-4d72-98ae-c42d88b01969?tab=AllReplies#tabs)

> I upgraded windows 7 enterprise to windows 8 (build 9200, 26 Oct 2012
>   release) there was no response from the the trackpad and I was getting
>   code (1) error when trying to install manually the win 7 trackpad
>   driver, but a mouse worked fine. What worked for me to get back all
>   supported gestures and the trackpad is:
>
> 1. uninstall both trackpad drivers from device manager. For some reason I was seeing two trackpad devices.  (Type devmgmt.msc in Search
>      bar to access it).
> 2. Then right click on the trackpad device chose update driver -> "choose location on the computer" -> then "let me pick from list of
>      devices" -> select **"usb input device" !!!** for both trackpad
>      divers.
> 3. Then simply run the bootcamp 4 disk, but do a **repair**. **Everything works fine.**
>
> (Macbook pro early 2011 13" with latest lion and dual boot with
>   windows 8 enterprise)

Answer (score 1):

just install bootcamp and restart 
first you expand hidden icons click bootcamp button that show 4 options 
click on bootcamp control panel windows ask the permission just click on yes 
bootcamp control panel is open, select track pad , select checkbox you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes the following article entitled **"Enabling Multi Apple Trackpad on Windows 8"** published on November 25th 2012 is written in Indonesian, however you can translate it into English with Google Chrome.

http://ariel4ever.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/mengaktifkan-apple-multi-trackpad-pada-windows-8/

The article will guide you through the necessary steps to accomplish what you wish to achieve.